# Kummer-Dedekind's factorisation theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

For a number field extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$
one can factorise almost all prime ideals $(p)$ in the extension $K$, 
except finitely many, easily by factorising minimal polynomials in finite fields.

Is there a simply written reference for the precise statement of this result stated 
for extensions $K/L$ where $L$ is a general number field rather than $\mathbb{Q}$?

I know that the interesting problem is that of factorising every prime ideal
in the extension but here I am only interested in having a simple and nice statement 
that works for not necessarily all primes.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the general statement as presented in Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, p.47-48:

> [image]